# How to print an object as JSON to console in Angular2?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm using a service to load my form data into an array in my angular2 app.
The data is stored like this:

```
arr = []
arr.push({title:name})
```

When I do a `console.log(arr)`, it is shown as Object. What I need is to see it
as `[ { 'title':name } ]`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))`

Answer (score 14):

you may use below,

```
  JSON.stringify({ data: arr}, null, 4);
```

this will nicely format your data with indentation.

Comment: @Bijithkomalan It's great that you thanked Madhu; if an answer worked for you please select and upvote

Comment: Nice, thanks.  This is the kind of simple solution I expected to be able to find but didn't know where to look.  Even better is just `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))` if you don't need the formatting and just want to see how the object might be passed to a REST endpoint or the like.

Answer (score 2):

To print out readable information. You can use `console.table()` which is much easier to read than JSON:

```
console.table(data);
```

> This function takes one mandatory argument data, which must be an array or an object, and one additional optional parameter columns.
>
> It logs data as a table. Each element in the array (or enumerable property if data is an object) will be a row in the table

Example:
[image]

[image]

Comment: While this indeed does work, I don't see that it answers OP's question.

Comment: TIL `console.table(x)`. looks nice!

Answer (score 0):

first convert your JSON string to Object using `.parse()` method and then you can print it in console using `console.table('parsed sring goes here')`.

e.g.

```
const data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
console.table(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the JSON Pipe operator in the HTML file. As the JSON info was needed only for debugging purposes, this method was suitable for me. Sample given below:

```
<p>{{arr | json}}</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could log each element of the array separately

```
arr.forEach(function(e){console.log(e)});
```

Since your array has just one element, this is the same as logging `{'title':name}`

Comment: Maximum effort for the same results you could achieve with JSON.stringify()

Answer (score -2):

you can print any object

```
console.log(this.anyObject);
```

when you write

```
console.log('any object' + this.anyObject);
```

this will print

```
any object [object Object]
```

Comment: This is kind of exactly what OP said they *didn't* want to do.